# Use SgmlReader on Window Phone Application

Tags: xml, xhtml, html-parsing, sgmlreader

Is there any way to include SgmlReader for Window Phone Application?
I can't install it by Install-package SgmlReader
incompatiable asssembly error

if this is not possible,is there any alternative way to perform the HTML to XML in Window Phone Application 8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version did you use?  The latest code and nuget package is available at: https://github.com/mindtouch/sgmlreader